# Mysql query string minus(-) sign issue

Tags: java, spring

When using special character in MySql query :

`String query = "select ID,Age,Income (k$),Score (1-100) from employee";
PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(query);
ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery();`

getting following error:

java.sql.SQLException: Bad format for number 'ID,Age,Income (k$),Score (1-100)' in column 1.

Comment: Why do you want to use dollar sign inside income?

Comment: What are the columns of your table actually called?

Comment: Please provide more information!! your table data,your database?

Comment: get resolved by adding `` to each column like "select \`ID\`,\`Age\`,\`Income (k$)\`,\`Score (1-100)\` from employee"

Answer (score 0):

Get resolved by adding `` to each column like "select `ID`,`Age`,`Income (k$)`,`Score (1-100)` from employee"